# Javascript > On element.value Changed

Tags: javascript

I've made an input component similar to PayPal's new input components:

```
<div class="panel panel-default input-panel">
    <div class="panel-body input-body">
        <div class="input-caption">Firstname</div>
        <input type="text" class="input-value" id="testinput">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: 1]

Everything works as I expect when interacting with the elements manually.

However, if I set the input value element's `.value` property using JavaScript, the following happens:

```
document.getElementById("testinput").value = 'hello';
```

[image: 2]

I've tried heaps to try and hook changing of the `.value` property with no love.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x1ztxuqq/

Comment: What do you intend to achieve with that?

Comment: Post the heap of code.

Comment: You need to trigger the onchange event to refresh the display,  `$('#testinput').trigger('change');`

Comment: I would suggest you use (example) placeholder="Surname".  Then you don't need any other script, maybe just some css to style it

Comment: @Rowland: I want the caption to resize and position when .value is set

Comment: @Pointy: I made a fiddle :)

Comment: @Teh: I dont want to have to call an event each time i set .value

Comment: @Emmanuel Delay: As far as i can see, u cant position a place holder nor have it visible when there is a value

Comment: I found this fiddle that acheives what im after. https://jsfiddle.net/273ntk5s/1262/

Answer (score 0):

You can fire an onchange event in the button click handler.

**Replace**

`document.getElementById("testinput").value = 'hello';`

**With**

```
document.getElementById('testinput').value = 'hello'; document.getElementById('testinput').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```